# Avoiding facebook messenger sounds and icons while synchronizing messages

Tags: applications, notifications, sync, facebook, facebook-messenger

I have an android Samsung S4 phone.

As far as I can remember Facebook Messenger app has always had this annoyance: when I connect my cellphone to the internet the app synchronizes and downloads all the past messages as a conversation history.

The problem is that every old message is downloaded and notifications are continuous since those messages are **new** for my cellphone. It's a continuous ringing sound since old messages are treated as new, the small chat icon is also constantly present on the screen per each contact I contacted before my cellphone's update.

I would like the app either to synchronize silently or not to synchronize at all since **it seems to ignore the synchronize/don't synchronize button** I have in the top bar.

I need to use facebook messenger to communicate with some friends who just use facebook but this problem is terribly annoying me.

Comment: What about disabling notifications of facebook messages? You can't modify the facebook behavior: it is a whatsapp like messenger with the difference that all the messages are stored in the cloud, but all messages must be downloaded always.

Comment: Unfortunately it is of no use. For whatever reason I de-checked the "Enable notifications" for the messenger app but they kept bothering me as soon as I connected.

Comment: Actually this isn't normal behaviour of the app. It should remember which messages have already been delivered and read and not send notifications of these messages. Only new, unread messages should cause a notification.

Comment: Any other friend I have experiences the same behavior. They have many different smartphones and android versions so this cannot be a coincidence.